# Codeigniter Auto_link doesn't work bug

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I've got a html WYSIWYG editor for staff to create very basic text pages on our website with. I use PHP's `nl2br` function to convert newlines to `<br>` tags, however I have this problem:

If a user enters the string: `This is a test link http://website.com`

the `auto_link` function works as expected. However, If I have this:

```
This is a test link<br>http://website.com
```

Then the `auto_link` function doesn't work.

I've narrowed it down to the fact the website address needs a space before it, and that this is the regex used in CI:

```
#(^|\s|\()((http(s?)://)|(www\.))(\w+[^\s\)\<]+)#i
```

I'm not the most fluent in Regular expressions, but if I change the above expression to:

```
#(^|\>|\s|\()((http(s?)://)|(www\.))(\w+[^\s\)\<]+)#i
```

(Note the added `|\>`in the first capture), then it works fine, however I don't know enough of expressions to know if this will mess up the functionality.

It doesn't seem to matter if a tag starts directly after the address, but it does matter if there isn't a space before the address.

Any help, or information would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hard to understand you needs.. Are you trying to match only the links which was preceded by a space?

Comment: `but it does matter if there isn't a space before the address.` , `(?<!\s)....` asserts that the match won't be preceded by a space character.

Comment: Sorry, without changes to the CI function, it works completely fine. It's only if I prepend the URL with the `>` symbol that it breaks.